# Why do I get negative numbers in this Haskell program?

Tags: math, haskell, functional-programming

I am trying to create a program that calculates the quadratic formula, but it turns out that it always gives me a negative number and I can't find the reason why?

```
equation::(Double,Double,Double)->Double
equation(x,y,z)=(-y-sqrt(y^2+4*x*z))/(2*x)
```

Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: Why is your function uncurried? Yuck!

Comment: Hey, if one of our answers has answered your question, could you please accept it (click the check mark next to the voting arrows)? That way we know that your problem was solved. If your problem hasn't been solved, can you leave a comment explaining what needs to be done so we can improve our answers.

Answer (score 6):

You're implementing the quadratic equation incorrectly. There's a square root in your equation, and square roots give a positive and a negative number (`2*2` and `-2*-2` both get `4`). So you want something like this:

```
equation::(Double,Double,Double)->(Double,Double)
equation(x,y,z)=(((-1 * y + ( sqrt ( y^2 - (4 * x * z))))/(2 * x)),((-1 * y - ( sqrt ( y^2 - (4 * x * z))))/(2 * x)))
```

or this (the previous version keeps the formatting that you used in your original sample, while this example is cleaner and easier to follow [imho])

```
quad :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> a -> (a,a)
quad x y z = 
        let a = ((-1 * y + ( sqrt ( y^2 - (4 * x * z))))/(2 * x))
            b = ((-1 * y - ( sqrt ( y^2 - (4 * x * z))))/(2 * x))
        in (a,b)
```

`a` is the number outputted for the *positive* square root, and `b` is the number outputted for the *negative* square root.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't always give me a negative number:

```
Prelude> equation (-1) 4 1
3.732050807568877
```

Just as one would get with e.g. Python:

```
>>> (-4 - math.sqrt(16 - 4))/-2
3.7320508075688772
```

If you want the roots of the quadratic equation, though, you want `y^2 - 4*x*z`, where you have addition rather than subtraction.

Answer (score 1):

Since your definition has a minus sign in front of the `sqrt`, it always yields the smaller of the two numbers in question.  That is often negative, but not necessarily so:

```
Prelude> equation (2, -4, -2)
1.0
```

(The version of the formula I learned at school is slightly different with regard to the sign of the `4*x*z` part, but that obviously depends on whether the equation to be solved is of the form `x*X^2 + y*X + z = 0` or `x*X^2 + y*X = z`, so I'll just assume that it isn't a typo.)